# Pine script Up/Down volume

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Below is the original code for the TV Up/Down indicator.
I want to change the condition under the switch:

```
if close > previous close
   posVol += volume

if close < previous close
   posVol -= volume
```

No matter what I try, I don't know or won't let me change the conditions. (I cannot save the previous close data.)

```
//@version=5


lowerTimeframeTooltip = "The indicator scans lower timeframe data to approximate Up/Down volume.
By default, the timeframe is chosen automatically. These inputs override this with a custom timeframe.
 \n\nHigher timeframes provide more historical data, but the data will be less precise."
useCustomTimeframeInput = input.bool(false, "Use custom timeframe", tooltip = lowerTimeframeTooltip)
lowerTimeframeInput = input.timeframe("1", "Timeframe")
upAndDownVolume() =>
    posVol = 0.0
    negVol = 0.0
    
    switch  
        close >  open     => posVol += volume
        close <  open     => negVol -= volume
        close >= close[1] => posVol += volume
        close <  close[1] => negVol -= volume

    [posVol, negVol]

lowerTimeframe = switch
    useCustomTimeframeInput => lowerTimeframeInput
    timeframe.isseconds     => "1S"
    timeframe.isintraday    => "1"
    timeframe.isdaily       => "5"
    => "60"

[upVolumeArray, downVolumeArray] = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, lowerTimeframe, `upAndDownVolume())

upVolume = array.sum(upVolumeArray)
downVolume = array.sum(downVolumeArray)
delta = upVolume + downVolume`
plot(upVolume, "Up Volume", style = plot.style_columns, color=color.new(color.green, 60))
plot(downVolume, "Down Volume", style = plot.style_columns, color=color.new(color.red, 60))
plotchar(delta, "delta", "—", location.absolute, color = delta > 0 ? color.green : color.red, size =size.tiny)

var cumVol = 0.
cumVol += nz(volume)
if barstate.islast and cumVol == 0
    runtime.error("The data vendor doesn't provide volume data for this symbol.")
```